# How can I get the source code of “RUS” and “PQF”

Tags: q#, clifford-group

Currently, I’m studying these two papers:

[“Efficient Synthesis of Universal Repeat-Until-Success Circuits”](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.5320) and
[“Efficient synthesis of probabilistic quantum circuits with fallback”](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3552).

I want the source code of these two papers to reimplement their experiments, but I can’t find the source in anywhere. Is there any method to get the source code?

Besides, on the website
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/quantum/repeat-until-success/
They say the quantum programming language “Q#” provides the ”Repeat until success” function. Can this function transfer the arbitrary single qubit gate into a sequence of Clifford+T gates? Is the implementation of the function followed by the paper “Efficient Synthesis of Universal Repeat-Until-Success Circuits”?
Thanks for answering my question !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, if the code is not referenced in the paper or attached to it on arxiv.org, you might want to reach out to the authors to ask about sharing the code - I don't think there's a different method to get it.

For the second question, "repeat until success" is not a library function, it's a general pattern implemented using Q# [repeat-until-success loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/quantum/user-guide/language/statements/conditionalloops#repeat-statement): apply some gates to the qubits, measure a subset of qubits, if the measurement result doesn't match your expectations, apply fixup gates and repeat. This pattern can be used not only to implement unitaries, but for other purposes as well, for example, preparing states.

The code this page refers to can be found at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/quantum/tree/main/samples/algorithms/repeat-until-success) (the "Browse code" link at the top of the page); it gives examples of implementing specific unitaries from the paper [Repeat-Until-Success: Non-deterministic decomposition of single-qubit unitaries](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.1074).